# Changing page content without changing url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently working on a project, but i just got stuck in something. It's supposed to be an inside tour of a building. [Click here to see the project.](https://github.com/pedrocaseiro/projeto_jeknowledge)

Right now i've only made one of the rooms, in which I used bpopup and Image Mapping. What i wanna do next, is being able to click on the door of the image and change the page to the next room, without changing the url of the page to create a fluide effect. Any tips?

Comment: Why don't you use AJAX?

Comment: what i've found is that people commonly use AJAX to change page url without reloading page, and that's not what I want, but i'll give it another look, maybe what I wanna do is possible with AJAX

Comment: You could use some existing library as [JQM](https://jquerymobile.com/) to change pages via AJAX (all the content can be on same page also, check the [docs/examples](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/)). Please note that your template is not responsive, some rooms will not be visible.

Comment: What do you mean by some rooms will not be visible?

Comment: Resize the browser to 320px width and you will see.

Comment: It's supposed to work on desktops only, because you can't use image mapping in smartphones tablets etc, that's why it's not responsive :/

Comment: What do you mean  by "change the page to next room" ? Do you want to just replace the current image with another image ?

Comment: Yes, i wanna replace this image (this room) with the following room which will have image mapping and bpopup.

Comment: you can make an AJAX request and return the src of the image from server and replace the source of the current <img>

Comment: will that work with image mapping? because with a new image i need to change all the coordinates.

Comment: I am not sure about the image mapping, but if it requires some kind of calculation based on image src/id/tag then it could be possible.

Comment: After all the answers, i think i'll do it changing the page url, it's much more practical and the result is the same. Thanks everyone :)

Comment: jquery tabs would do this.. no URL change needed.